Посоветуйте годный учебник по языку lisp
Мне нужен хороший учебник по языку Lisp. Можете порекомендовать какие-то книги или онлайн-ресурсы, которые хорошо объясняют основы языка Lisp и его применение в программировании?

sicp и practical common lisp

Ну, какой-нибудь On Lisp от Paul Graham
